Excel Lambdas for Filtration Lookup
Background
I have an ongoing challenge in Excel, where I must match differing descriptions of the same object.  Originally, there were only two alternatives:

Use a dropdown list in Excel, which pulls from the other description column.  This features "live" autocompletion, but it matches only phrase at a time.


Apply a fuzzy join in Power Query, and display the potential matches in Excel.  This matches on multiple fragments, but it is not "live" — one must refresh the query — and its accuracy is unreliable.


Furthermore, neither alternative permits the exclusion of undesirable keywords.
Excel Lambdas
I recently discovered the joys of LAMBDA().  By defining it as a name in Excel, we can create lightweight UDFs without VBA modules!
= LAMBDA(arg_1, arg_2, [arg_3], ..., [arg_n], LET(
    arg_3_, IF(ISOMITTED(arg_3), dflt_3, arg_3),
    ...,
    arg_n_, IF(ISOMITTED(arg_n), dflt_n, arg_n),
    
    var_a, expr_a,
    var_b, expr_b,
    ...,
    
    return_expr
))


Solution
Using LAMBDA(), I have created a quartet of functions for "live" matching.  See the Code section for implementation.
FilterKeys()
This is the workhorse.  It accepts keywords from a row of cells; and it outputs its results in a column of cells.
FilterKeys(in_col, [out_col], [yes_row], [yes_any], [no_row], [no_all], [exact], [start_num])




Argument
Type
Default
Description




in_col
Column

The lookup column where matches are found.  This is like the 1st column in a VLOOKUP().


out_col
Column
in_col
The return column whose output corresponds to the matches.  This is like the col_index_numth column in a VLOOKUP().When out_col is skipped, the matches from in_col are shown.


yes_row
Row

A row of cells with one keyword apiece, which matches must contain.  More keywords will narrow the results.


yes_any
Logical
FALSE
Should we match where any keywords are found (TRUE)?  Then more keywords will expand the results.


no_row
Row

A row of cells with one keyword apiece, which matches must exclude.  More keywords will narrow the results.


no_all
Logical
FALSE
Should we only exclude where all keywords are found (TRUE)?  This will expand the results.


exact
Logical
FALSE
Should matching be exact (TRUE) like FIND(): case sensitive and letter-for-letter?  Otherwise, it is like SEARCH(): insensitive and with wildcards (* and ?).


start_num
Number
1
Where in each text should matching start?  With (say) a 3, the search would begin on the 3rd letter, as with FIND() and SEARCH().



CountFiltered()
This is a convenience function.  It counts the cell results found by FilterKeys(), or shows a blank if no keywords were searched.
CountFiltered(filtered, [yes_row], [no_row])




Argument
Type
Default
Description




filtered
Cell

The cell containing the FilterKeys() formula.Note: Be sure to put a # after the cell address, to capture the spillover: A1#.


yes_row
Row

The row of cells used as yes_row for FilterKeys().


no_row
Row

The row of cells used as no_row for FilterKeys().



MatchKeys()
This is much like FilterKeys(), but with a textual list rather than separate cells.  It accepts keywords in a textual list, which fits in a single cell; and it outputs its results in a textual list, which also fits in a single cell.
Note: Too many matches will yield a #CALC! error here, so try narrowing down your results.
MatchKeys(in_col, [out_col], [yes_keys], [yes_sep], [yes_any], [no_keys], [no_sep], [no_all], [exact], [start_num], [out_sep])




Argument
Type
Default
Description




in_col
Column

The lookup column where matches are found.  See in_col for FilterKeys().


out_col
Column
in_col
The return column whose output corresponds to the matches.  See out_col for FilterKeys().


yes_keys
Text

A list of keywords, which matches must contain.  See yes_row for FilterKeys().Note: Only insert spaces if you wish to match them.


yes_sep
Text
Newline
The separator between keywords in yes_keys.Note: Use AltEnter to insert a newline.


yes_any
Logical
FALSE
Should we match where any keywords are found (TRUE)?  See yes_any for FilterKeys().


no_keys
Text

A list of keywords, which matches must exclude.  See no_row for FilterKeys().


no_sep
Text
yes_sep
The separator in no_keys.When no_sep is skipped, the no_keys are read like the yes_keys.


no_all
Logical
FALSE
Should we only exclude where all keywords are found (TRUE)?  See no_all for FilterKeys().


exact
Logical
FALSE
Should matching be exact (TRUE)?  See exact for FilterKeys().


start_num
Number
1
Where in each text should matching start?  See start_num for FilterKeys().


out_sep
Text
Newline
The separator between the results.Note: Use Home » Wrap Text to view newlines.



CountMatched()
This is to MatchKeys() what CountFiltered() is to FilterKeys().  It counts the list results found by MatchKeys(), or shows a blank if no keywords were searched.
CountMatched(matched, [yes_keys], [no_keys], [out_sep])




Argument
Type
Default
Description




matched
Text

The textual list of results output by MatchKeys().


yes_keys
Text

The textual list used as yes_keys for MatchKeys().


no_keys
Text

The textual list used as no_keys for MatchKeys().


out_sep
Text
Newline
The separator used as out_sep for MatchKeys().



Code
FilterKeys
= LAMBDA(in_col, [out_col], [yes_row], [yes_any], [no_row], [no_all], [exact], [start_num], LET(
    has_yes, NOT(ISOMITTED(yes_row)),
    has_no, NOT(ISOMITTED(no_row)),
    
    out_col_, IF(ISOMITTED(out_col), in_col, out_col),
    yes_any_, IF(ISOMITTED(yes_any), FALSE, yes_any),
    no_all_, IF(ISOMITTED(no_all), FALSE, no_all),
    exact_, IF(ISOMITTED(exact), FALSE, exact),
    start_num_, IF(ISOMITTED(start_num), 1, start_num),
    
    yes_fn, IF(yes_any_, LAMBDA(x, OR(x)), LAMBDA(x, AND(x))),
    no_fn, IF(no_all_, LAMBDA(x, AND(x)), LAMBDA(x, OR(x))),
    
    yes_keyed, IF(has_yes, yes_row <> "", FALSE),
    no_keyed, IF(has_no, no_row <> "", FALSE),
    
    use_yes, AND(has_yes, OR(yes_keyed)),
    use_no, AND(has_no, OR(no_keyed)),
    
    yes_keys, IF(use_yes, FILTER(yes_row, yes_keyed, ""), ""),
    no_keys, IF(use_no, FILTER(no_row, no_keyed, ""), ""),
    
    yes_unq, IF(use_yes, UNIQUE(yes_keys, TRUE, FALSE), ""),
    no_unq, IF(use_no, UNIQUE(no_keys, TRUE, FALSE), ""),
    
    yes_locs, IFS(
        NOT(use_yes), 0,
        exact_, FIND(yes_unq, in_col, start_num_),
        TRUE, SEARCH(yes_unq, in_col, start_num_)
    ),
    no_locs, IFS(
        NOT(use_no), 0,
        exact_, FIND(no_unq, in_col, start_num_),
        TRUE, SEARCH(no_unq, in_col, start_num_)
    ),
    
    yes_match, IF(use_yes,
        BYROW(NOT(ISERROR(yes_locs)), yes_fn),
        FALSE
    ),
    no_match, IF(use_no,
        BYROW(NOT(ISERROR(no_locs)), no_fn),
        FALSE
    ),
    
    match, IFS(
        AND(use_yes, use_no), (yes_match * NOT(no_match)) = 1,
        use_yes, yes_match,
        use_no, no_match,
        TRUE, FALSE
    ),
    
    use, OR(use_yes, use_no),
    IF(use,
        FILTER(out_col_, match, ""),
        ""
    )
))

CountFiltered
= LAMBDA(filtered, [yes_row], [no_row], LET(
    has_yes, NOT(ISOMITTED(yes_row)),
    has_no, NOT(ISOMITTED(no_row)),
    
    yes_keyed, IF(has_yes, yes_row <> "", FALSE),
    no_keyed, IF(has_no, no_row <> "", FALSE),
    
    skip_yes, NOT(AND(has_yes, OR(yes_keyed))),
    skip_no, NOT(AND(has_no, OR(no_keyed))),
    skip, AND(skip_yes, skip_no),
    
    n_rows, ROWS(filtered),
    is_0, IF(n_rows = 1, filtered = "", FALSE),
    
    IFS(
    skip, "",
        is_0, 0,
        TRUE, n_rows
    )
))

MatchKeys
= LAMBDA(in_col, [out_col], [yes_keys], [yes_sep], [yes_any], [no_keys], [no_sep], [no_all], [exact], [start_num], [out_sep], LET(
    has_yes, NOT(ISOMITTED(yes_keys)),
    has_no, NOT(ISOMITTED(no_keys)),
    
    yes_sep_, IF(ISOMITTED(yes_sep), CHAR(10), yes_sep),
    no_sep_, IF(ISOMITTED(no_sep), yes_sep_, no_sep),
    out_sep_, IF(ISOMITTED(out_sep), CHAR(10), out_sep),
    
    use_yes, AND(has_yes, yes_keys <> ""),
    use_no, AND(has_no, no_keys <> ""),
    
    yes_row_, IF(use_yes, TEXTSPLIT(yes_keys, yes_sep_, , TRUE, 0, NA()), ""),
    no_row_, IF(use_no, TEXTSPLIT(no_keys, no_sep_, , TRUE, 0, NA()), ""),
    
    use, OR(use_yes, use_no),
    IF(use,
        TEXTJOIN(out_sep_, TRUE, FilterKeys(in_col, out_col, yes_row_, yes_any, no_row_, no_all, exact, start_num)),
        ""
    )
))

CountMatched
= LAMBDA(matched, [yes_keys], [no_keys], [out_sep], LET(
    out_sep_, IF(ISOMITTED(out_sep), CHAR(10), out_sep),
    
    skip_yes, IF(ISOMITTED(yes_keys), FALSE, yes_keys = ""),
    skip_no, IF(ISOMITTED(no_keys), FALSE, no_keys = ""),
    
    skip, AND(skip_yes, skip_no),
    IFS(
    skip, "",
        matched = "", 0,
        TRUE, ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(matched, , out_sep_, FALSE, 0, NA()))
    )
))


Very nice!  Both in functionality and presentation.  Are you using the Lambdas in a Data Validation formula?  Could you add a download link to the workbook?

@TinMan  Thank you for the kind words!  As for Data Validation formulas, I am not using the lambdas there: I believe they prohibit defined names as functions.  Formulas for data validation tend to be a lot more restrictive than regular formulas in cells...

How would you use the lambdas to recreate the example of the quiz?

@Greedo  Suppose this is a Quiz table with three columns: #, Question, and Answer.  Suppose also that the astronauts' names exist as the Full Name column in a separate Astronauts table. Then I would insert three columns between Question and Answers: namely Yes, No, and Matches. The Yes and No columns are for manual entry of keywords, separated by a comma (,). The Matches column displays the matches via the formula = MatchKeys(Astronauts[Full Name], , [@Yes], ",", , [@No]), which should be wrapped onto separate lines within the cell.

@Greedo  After visually inspecting the resulting matches under Matches, it is trivial to select the proper answer, in the dropdown under Answer.
